# Trigger that triggers when a single column (boolean) is updated from TRUE to FALSE (not vice versa)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have limited experience creating trigger.  Here is one I created recently:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NameTrigger]
ON [dbo].[dbUSNs]
after INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @URNs varchar(100)
    declare @Forenames varchar(200)
    declare @Surname varchar(100)
    declare @Reference int

    set @URNs = ''
    set @Forenames = ''
    set @Surname = ''
    set @Reference = 0

    declare PersonCursor cursor FOR   
    select 
    Replace(Replace(Replace(Forenames,char(39),''),'-',''),' ',''),
    Replace(Replace(Replace(Surname,char(39),''),'-',''),' ',''),
    Reference,USN from inserted
    open PersonCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor INTO @Forenames, @Surname, @Reference, @URNs
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                    BEGIN
                            update Person set ForenamesCleansed = @Forenames, SurnameCleansed= @Surname, URNsCleansed=@URNs
                            where reference = @Reference        
                    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor INTO @Forenames, @Surname, @Reference,@URNs
                    END

    CLOSE PersonCursor
    DEALLOCATE PersonCursor
END
```

I want to created a trigger that is triggered when a specific column (called update) changes from 0 to 1.  Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to create the trigger to act on all changes, and then manually check inside the trigger whether it was `0 -> 1` or `1 -> 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Sql Server so:

you have two special tables:

`INSERTED` and `DELETED`.

These tables works in this way:

When you apply an `INSERT` statement in the trigger you'll find full the table `INSERTED`

When you apply an `UPDATE` statement in the trigger you'll find full the table `INSERTED` and `DELETED`

When you apply an `DELETE` statement in the trigger you'll find full the table `DELETED`

In the INSERTED table you'll find all new value, in the DELETED, you'll find the old value, so when you write a trigger you can check the old and the new value of your boolean field, so when the condition is satisfacted you can apply the other changes you want.

Answer (score 1):

You just need an extra `IF` within your cursor logic:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor INTO @Forenames, @Surname, @Reference, @URNs
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF (inserted.[Update] = 0 AND deleted.[Update] = 1) --Added
                BEGIN
                    update Person set ForenamesCleansed = @Forenames, SurnameCleansed= @Surname, URNsCleansed=@URNs
                    where reference = @Reference        
                    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor INTO @Forenames, @Surname, @Reference,@URNs
                END
            END
        END
```

You may want to invert the logic, there is a mismatch between the question and its title regarding the change direction.